# Optimise calculs with table fields and deal with possible None values

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have 3 differents tables : `Price`, `Recipe` and `Item`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.URLField()

class Recette(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    qte_ressource_1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ressource_1 = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ressource_1')

    qte_ressource_2 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ressource_2 = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ressource_2')

    qte_ressource_3 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ressource_3 = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ressource_3')

    qte_ressource_4 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ressource_4 = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ressource_4')

    qte_ressource_5 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ressource_5 = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ressource_5')

    qte_ressource_6 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ressource_6 = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ressource_6')

    qte_ressource_7 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ressource_7 = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ressource_7')

    qte_ressource_8 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ressource_8 = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ressource_8')

class Prix_x1(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    prix = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    saved_at = models.DateTimeField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Each Item can have a Recipe and a recipe is composed of 1 to 8 items with a quantity associated to each ingredient.
And all of the items have a price.

Here is what i want :

For all item that have a recipe, i want to calcul the total price of this recipe, that mean to get the price of all the ingredients. The problem is that i defined my recipe model to have a maximum of of 8 ingredients but a recipe can have only 2 for exemple, so the rest of the ingredient is set to None.

I tried something like that :

```
items = Item.objects.all().select_related('recette').exclude(recette__isnull=True).annotate(
    prix1=Subquery(
        Prix_x1.objects.filter(
            item=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('prix').order_by('-saved_at')[:1]
    )
)

for item in items:
    prix_craft, is_recette_ok = item.recette.get_recette_price()
    prix = item.prix1
    if is_recette_ok and prix:
        gain = prix - prix_craft
        prices.append({'name': item.name,
                       'key': item.pk,
                       'prix_hdv': prix,
                       'prix_craft': prix_craft,
                       'gain': gain,
                       'pourcentage_gain': np.around((gain / prix_craft) * 100)})
```

and i created a get_recette_price() like that :

```
def get_fields(self):
    values = []
    for field in Recette._meta.fields:
        if field.value_to_string(self) != 'None':
            if field.name not in ('item', 'id'):
                values.append(int(field.value_to_string(self)))

    return values

def get_recette_price(self):

    fields = self.get_fields()
    quantites = fields[::2]
    ressources = Item.objects.filter(id__in=fields[1::2]).annotate(
        prix1=Subquery(
            Prix_x1.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('pk')).values('prix').order_by('-saved_at')[:1]
        )
    ).values_list('prix1', flat=True)

    is_recette_ok = True
    total = 0
    for quantite, ressource in zip(quantites, ressources):
        if quantite and ressource:
            total += quantite * ressource
        else:
            is_recette_ok = False
            break
    return total, is_recette_ok
```

But the code is really long to execute.
I don't know how to optimise it and deal with the None value if the recipe doesnt have 8 ingredients.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: This looks like bad modeling. Typically one uses a `ManyToManyField` with a `through=...` model in between that can store the quantity. By doing this with eight foreign keys, the logic will be quite complicated (since it can be related to one of these eight fields, or even through two fields!).

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.I pretty new to this so do you have a small code exemple that i can use to modify my modeling ? Thanks !

Comment: And to clarify, an object can appear only once in a recipe !